# Call notifyItemRangechanged when text in searchbar is written Recyclerview android

Tags: android, animation, android-recyclerview, searchview, notify

I would like to add an `animation` on my `RecyclerView` every time the user types something in the `SearchBar`. I already have implemented a `Filter` method to filter the items, but fail to call `notifyItemrangechanged` in `OnQuerytextChanged`, so the appears. I have already tried something like this:

```
@Override
                public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {


                    istyping = true;

                    ArrayList<String> templist = new ArrayList<>();

                    mSearchQuery = newText;

 //this line -->   adapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(0, namelistwithnumber.size());    <---



                    for (String temp : namelistwithnumber) {
                        if (temp.toLowerCase().contains(newText.toLowerCase())) {
                            templist.add(temp);
                        }
                    }

                    if (newText.isEmpty()){
                        mainlist.setAdapter(null);
                        adapter = new MyRecyclerViewAdapter(MainActivity.this, namelist);
                        mainlist.setAdapter(adapter);
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        istyping = false;
                    }

                    if (templist.size() == 0) {
                        mainlist.setAdapter(null);
                        noresults.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    } else {
                        if (!newText.isEmpty()){
                          adapter = new MyRecyclerViewAdapter(MainActivity.this, templist);
                            mainlist.setAdapter(adapter);
                            noresults.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            adapter.setClickListener(MainActivity.this);

                        }
                        noresults.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    }

                    return true;
                }
```

This is what I want to achieve:

[image: animation]

Any help is appreciated!!

Comment: is your data is coming from json?

Comment: My data is stored in an ArrayList<String>

Comment: check my solution). It doesn't introduce any new concepts and includes just few modifications to your existing code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sina's answer seems good, it has good practices(except redundant dataBinding), but since you did not accept it, i assume you don't want to rewrite your code with those additional concepts. So here is simple solution:

- Set `setHasStableIds(true)` to adapter
- Override `getItemId(int position)` inside adapter
- Add `DefaultItemAnimator()` to RecyclerView

---

Step by step guide:

**1. Add default itemAnimator to your RecyclerView**

```
mainlist.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
```

**2. Add function to adapter for updating list**

You should not reinitialize your `MyRecyclerViewAdapter` every time you change List of items. Remove list from constructor! Instead declare member varialbe `List<NameListwithNumber> nameListWithNumber = new ArrayList<>();`  inside your dapter class and add a function to your adapter:

```
public void setItems(List<NameListwithNumber> newItems){
nameListWithNumber.clear();
nameListWithNumber.addAll(newItems);
notifydatasetChanged();
}
```

**3. Initialize adapter and set setHasStableIds(true)**

In your `Activity` declare your adapter as a global variable

```
private MyRecyclerViewAdapter  myAdapter;
```

*(i'm not sure why would you need activity instance inside adapter tho)*

and initialize it inside `onCreate()` method

```
 myAdapter = new MyRecyclerViewAdapter(MainActivity.this);
 myAdapter.setHasStableIds(true);
 mainList.setAdapter(myAdapter);
```

**4. Override  getItemId(int position) inside adapter**

inside your adapter add this function:

```
@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
   return nameListWithNumber.get(position).id;
}
```

if your model does not have **unique id** just use `return nameListWithNumber.get(position).hashCode();`

---

**Finally**
Inside your `public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText)`
you need to change

```
  if (newText.isEmpty()) {
       adapter.setItems(nameList)
       istyping = false;
    }
  else {
    adapter.setItems(tempList)
    noresults.setVisibility(templist.size() == 0 ? View.VISIBLE : View.INVISIBLE)
}
```

---

Heres is the result of the exact same approach with just filtering done differently.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is a complete working sample. I queried words out of a sample list, but you can do it from db or a web API. I used a fixed hight for recyclerView so all animations would be seen. There are lots of concepts  at work here: MVVM design pattern, LiveData, DataBinding, ... . For the best result there is no simple answer. If not familiar with these concepts look into them one by one.

**MainActivity.java**:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ActivityMainBinding binding;
    private SearchAdapter searchAdapter;
    private MainViewModel viewModel;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);
        viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MainViewModel.class);

        searchAdapter = new SearchAdapter();
        binding.recycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false));
        binding.recycler.setAdapter(searchAdapter);

        observeData();

        viewModel.queryWord("");

        binding.search.setOnQueryTextListener((new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                viewModel.queryWord(query);
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                viewModel.queryWord(newText);
                return false;
            }
        }));
    }

    private void observeData() {
        viewModel.getResult().observe(this, result -> {
            searchAdapter.submitList(result);
        });
    }
}
```

**MainViewModel.java**:

```
public class MainViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

    private ArrayList<String> namelistwithnumber;

    MutableLiveData<List<SearchResult>> result = new MutableLiveData<>();

    public MainViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
        super(application);
        namelistwithnumber = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList("aa", "ab", "ac", "ad", "ba", "bb", "bc", "bd", "ca", "cb", "cc", "cd", "da", "db", "dc", "dd"));
    }

    public void queryWord(String word) {
        ArrayList<SearchResult> templist = new ArrayList<>();
        int id = 0;

        if (word.equals("")) {
            for (String temp : namelistwithnumber) {
                id++;
                SearchResult anItem = new SearchResult(id, temp);
                templist.add(anItem);
            }
        } else {
            for (String temp : namelistwithnumber) {
                if (temp.toLowerCase().contains(word.toLowerCase())) {
                    id++;
                    SearchResult anItem = new SearchResult(id, temp);
                    templist.add(anItem);
                }
            }
        }
        result.setValue(templist);
    }

    public MutableLiveData<List<SearchResult>> getResult() {
        return result;
    }
}
```

**SearchAdapter.java**:

```
public class SearchAdapter extends ListAdapter<SearchResult, SearchAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private Context context;

    public SearchAdapter() {
        super(DIFF_CALLBACK);
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        context = parent.getContext();
        this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        ResultItemBinding binding = ResultItemBinding.inflate(mInflater, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(binding);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        SearchResult searchResult= getItem(position);
        holder.bind(searchResult);
    }


    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ResultItemBinding binding;

        ViewHolder(ResultItemBinding binding) {
            super(binding.getRoot());
            this.binding = binding;
        }

        void bind(SearchResult item) {
            binding.setResult(item);
        }
    }


    public static final DiffUtil.ItemCallback<SearchResult> DIFF_CALLBACK =
            new DiffUtil.ItemCallback<SearchResult>() {
                @Override
                public boolean areItemsTheSame(
                        @NonNull SearchResult oldUser, @NonNull SearchResult newUser) {
                    // User properties may have changed if reloaded from the DB, but ID is fixed
                    return oldUser.getWord().equals(newUser.getWord());
                }

                @Override
                public boolean areContentsTheSame(
                        @NonNull SearchResult oldUser, @NonNull SearchResult newUser) {
                    // NOTE: if you use equals, your object must properly override Object#equals()
                    // Incorrectly returning false here will result in too many animations.
                    return oldUser.getWord().equals(newUser.getWord());
                }
            };
}
```

**SearchResult.java**:

```
public class SearchResult {
    private long id;
    private String word;

    public SearchResult(long id, String word) {
        this.id = id;
        this.word = word;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getWord() {
        return word;
    }

    public void setWord(String word) {
        this.word = word;
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout>

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView
                android:id="@+id/search"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recycler"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="600dp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/search" />


        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

</layout>
```

**result_item.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="result"
            type="com.example.recyclerviewtest.SearchResult" />
    </data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/word"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:gravity="start|center_vertical"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:text="@{result.word}"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

**build.gradle**:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.recyclerviewtest"
        minSdkVersion 28
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildFeatures {
        dataBinding true
        // for view binding:
        // viewBinding true
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:15.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
}
```

Comment: you forgot opening tag for <layout> in activity_main. Since you didn't add MainViewModel as variable to layout and not observing any data there, i assume you used binding for MainActivity just to avoid findViewById()? And why are  using binding in result_item, for the same reason? Wouldn't  binding.word.setText(item.word) be much simpler without extra  <data> <variable> stuff? I just always hated dataBinding, maybe i'm missing out something, some benefit? Could you please clear things up for me? Because in example above it seems like unnecessary complication of things.

Comment: You can avoid it if you wish. As you said it is almost useless in actvity_main.

Comment: Ty for mentioning begining tag

Comment: In `areItemsTheSame()` you should check equality of ids, not contents.

Comment: Yeah but whats the point? It is just a sample data. The difference would remain hidden to the reader. Still, the comment mentions it.

Comment: Actually I didn't have any time to check the answers on stackoverflow, sorry, I would except both Sina's answer and Rinat's answer.

Answer (score 0):

You create a new Adapter every time this means there is no previous data... which in turn means there cant be any animation ;-)

What you need to do is to create one ArrayList in the Activity in reference this in the Adapter

then in the method you post you modify the items in the ArrayList then you just call adapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(0, list.size());
ie

```
...
private ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
private MyRecyclerViewAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ...
    //create your adapter and reference the ArrayList
    adapter = new MyRecyclerViewAdapter(MainActivity.this, list);
   ...


@Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {

   istyping = true;
   ArrayList<String> templist = new ArrayList<>();
   mSearchQuery = newText;
   for (String temp : namelistwithnumber) {
     if (temp.toLowerCase().contains(newText.toLowerCase())) {
       templist.add(temp);
     }
   }
  //no need to set a new Adapter, the Adapter already has the ref to the ArrayList 
  //so just modify it and tell the adapter it has changed animation will be handled 
  //automatically
  list.clear();
  list.addAll(templist);
  adapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(0, list.size());
  ...
```

Comment: Looks suspicious... Did you test it? I might be wrong, but if done your, won't adapter update only items from 0 to list.size() and keep the rest unchanged?